# Disambiguate the [semantics] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantics) tag is somewhat confusing: some questions with this tag are about [semantics of programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), but others are about [semantics in natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_semantics_(natural_language)).

Is it possible to disambiguate this tag to avoid this semantic ambiguity?

Comment: we need a punny title tradition of our own! "make [semantics] mean something!" :) P.S. A suggested rename of the second part: [nlp-semantics]

Comment: punny title for you: "What are the [semantics]?" I tried for all of five seconds.

Comment: Lets stop discussing semantics.

Comment: There's also a [tag:formal-semantics] tag, which might be about the same topic.

Comment: "Disambiguate the [semantics] tag" is already pretty close to a pun even without trying. - haha - "What is the meaning of [semantics]?" would also work. Or even "What are the semantics of [semantics]?"